# Opening an Excel doc from a URL and navigating to the desire sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open an Excel doc from an internal URL (which is why the link is not present in the code) and am trying to figure out why I cannot go to a specific sheet once the Excel doc is opened.

I can open the doc with no issues, but once I get to this line of the code `(Set ws = wb.Sheets("Version Control"))`,

I get a Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range error. It seems like I am getting this because the sheet name cannot be recognized. If that is the case, I am looking for help with how to resolve this and figure out how to manipulate a workbook once it is opened from a URL.

```
Option Explicit

Sub openDoc()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.navigate ("") ' <--- insert business URL here
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Set ws = wb.Sheets("Version Control") ' WHERE ERROR HAPPENS

ws.Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you verified what ActiveWorkbook is referencing? I can see this not being a reliable method to reference the file you are opening.

Comment: No, I haven't verified. How would that be done when this is tested?

Comment: Just do something like " MsgBox wb.Name " after you set wb and it will tell you the name of the workbook. It's possible ActiveWorkbook is referencing the workbook you are running the macro from and not the one you are opening, which is why the sheet reference is failing.

Comment: @linktheory You should be using `Application.Workbook("MyWorkbookname")` and also note that the sheet name is case sensitive.

Comment: @Wedge That definitely helped! It is referencing the workbook running the macro. Do you know what would be needed to reference the workbook being opened from the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very pretty, but assuming this is the only way you can open the excel files and you are only opening one at a time, you can just run a loop to wait until a workbook that is not the one you are running the macro from shows up. If you know the name of the workbook you will be looking for, you can make a more accurate check by looking for that instead.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

Do

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

    For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count

        If Workbooks(i).Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name And Workbooks(i).Name <> "PERSONAL.XLSB" Then
            Set wb = Workbooks(i)
            Exit Do
        End If

    Next

Loop
```

Comment: That logic worked great! I had to make small adjustments, but the logic helped in the final code. I made this edit to help with the loop:                                                   
If Workbooks(i).Name = "Tableau Report Tracker_.xlsx" Then

Answer (score 0):

If your URL returns a workbook then this should work:

```
Sub openDoc()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("yourURLhere")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Version Control") 
    ws.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: It would seem like that would work, but it doesn't. If it helps make things clearer about the website that houses the Excel doc, there is an Edit, Open and Download link next to each doc. I am using the URL for Open in my scenario. When I use Workbooks.Open("yourURLhere"), it acts like it is going to open, but freezes in the edit load screen.

Comment: It's difficult to make any suggestions without access to the URL

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I just can't post it because it is work-related and can only be used on intranet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub OpenWebXLS()
' *************************************************
' Define Workbook and Worksheet Variables
' *************************************************
Dim wkbMyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wkbWebWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksWebWorkSheet As Worksheet

Set wkbMyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

' *************************************************
' Open The Web Workbook
' *************************************************
Workbooks.Open ("http://www.richlocus.com/Illustrations/UploadedExcel.xls")

' *************************************************
' Set the Web Workbook and Worksheet Variables
' *************************************************
Set wkbWebWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksWebWorkSheet = ActiveSheet

' *************************************************
' Copy The Web Worksheet To My Workbook and Rename
' *************************************************
wksWebWorkSheet.Copy After:=wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = "MyNewWebSheet"

' *************************************************
' Close the Web Workbook
' *************************************************
wkbMyWorkbook.Activate
wkbWebWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for my scenario, as I am not trying to copy anything to a new workbook and I need to ensure that new sheets are not created for every workbook open.

Comment: I don't know why they are copying the sheet either, but if this method works to open the workbook instead of using IE, I would go for it. Workbook.Open returns the opened workbook object, so you can do " Set  wb = Workbooks.Open ("http://www.richlocus.com/Illustrations/UploadedExcel.xls") ". This way you make sure you are getting a reference to the workbook you opened.

Comment: @Wedge The only problem with this route is the website that houses the Excel doc, has an Edit, Open and Download link next to each doc. I am using the URL for Open in my scenario. When I use Workbooks.Open("myUrl"), it acts like it is going to open, but freezes in the edit load screen. That is the predicament that I am in. If I could somehow create a variable, or use some way other way to make the IE.navigate line of code be the reference to the workbook being opened, that would be most beneficial.